# Подгрузка контента методом .load() в django проекте

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

Как настроить url в методе .load()?
Суть проблемы:
Есть страница(strategy.html) с несколькими кнопками и таблицей, в которую подгружается контент, в зависимости от того, какая нажата кнопка.

```
    <body>
    <div class="btn-group starter-template" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="strategy1" autocomplete="off">Стратегия 1
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="strategy2" autocomplete="off">Стратегия 2
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="strategy3" autocomplete="off">Стратегия 3
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="starter-template" id="SOG">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <span>
                    <td>Колонка</td> <td>Колонка</td> <td>Колонка</td> <td>Колонка</td> <td>Колонка</td>
                </span>
            </tr>
                <div id="variants"></div> <!--Сюда должен быть подгружен контент-->
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
<script src="{% static "project/js/script.js" %}"></script>
```

Сам скрипт

```
$('#strategy1').on('click',function(){
    $("#variants").load("variants.html #strategy1")
})
$('#strategy2').on('click',function(){
    $("#variants").load("variants.html #strategy2")
})
$('#strategy3').on('click',function(){
    $("#variants").load("variants.html #strategy3")
})
```

И есть ещё один html-документ (variants.htlm), откуда должен подгружаться контент

```
<body>
<div id="strategy1"><td>strategy1</td> <td>strategy1</td> <td>strategy1</td> <td>strategy1</td> <td>strategy1</td></div>
<div id="strategy2"><td>strategy2</td> <td>strategy2</td> <td>strategy2</td> <td>strategy2</td> <td>strategy2</td></div>
<div id="strategy3"><td>strategy3</td> <td>strategy3</td> <td>strategy3</td> <td>strategy3</td> <td>strategy3</td></div>
</body>
```

Несмотря на то, что страница, куда нужно подгрузить контент, и страница с контентом лежат в одном каталоге, при нажатии кнопки выдается ошибка 404
"GET /project/strategy/variants.html HTTP/1.1" 404 3047. У меня какое-то глобальное непонимание происходящего( Проект делаю в Pycharm.

Comment: Я так понял, что вы отдаете strategy.html с помощью django. Есть ли у вас в url, по которому вы отдаете и variants.htlm? То что эти файлы лежат в одной директории ничего не значит, так как имеют значения только url django.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Да, в url были прописаны пути, но во views функция возвращала HttpResponse(request,'project/variants.html', после переделки на return render(request, 'project/variants.html') все заработало. И это главная моя ошибка, как я понял. А причина ошибки 404 заключается в том, что я неверно указывал адрес в скрипте.("**variants.html** #strategy1")->("**../variants/** #strategy1")

Answer (score 1):

Во views функция возвращала `HttpResponse(request,'project/variants.html')`, после переделки на `return render(request, 'project/variants.html')` все заработало. А причина ошибки 404 заключается в том, что я неверно указывал адрес в скрипте.`("variants.html #strategy1")`->`("../variants/ #strategy1")`